# Show that T is a unitary operator

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, linear-transformations

Let $V=W \oplus W^\perp$ and  $v=w_1+w_2$ with $ w_1  \in  W $ and $ w_2  \in  W^\perp $. Define $T:V \rightarrow V$ by $Tv=w_1-w_2$.

How can I show that $T$ is an unitary operator. Any thoughts or a way to start would be very appreciated

Thanks!!!

Comment: If you want to define an operator T, you have to say how it acts on *any* vector in its domain V. It seems you have only given its action on a single element v...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Observe that

$$\|Tv\|^2=\|Tw_1+Tw_2\|^2=\|w_1-w_2\|^2=\|w_1\|^2+\|w_2\|^2=\|v\|^2$$

where we had used the [pythagorean theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem#Inner_product_spaces) because $w_1$ and $w_2$ are orthogonal.

Answer (score 1):

You get the same result as in Masacroso's answer using the equivalent property that $T$ is unitary iff for any two vectors $v,u \in V$ we have $v \cdot u = Tv \cdot Tu$.

Now since any vector of $V$ can be decomposed in a unique way as a sum of two mutually orthogonal components let's say $v =v_1 + v_2$ and $u = u_1 + u_2$ with $v_1,u_1 \in W$ and $v_2,u_2 \in W^{\perp}$. Using the distributivity law of the inner product with respect to vector sum and the orthogonality of $W$ and $ W^{\perp}$ we get the following equalities:
$$v \cdot u = (v_1 + v_2) \cdot(u_1 +u _2) =v_1 \cdot u_1 + v_2 \cdot u_2 = (v_1 -v_2) \cdot (u_1 - u_2) = Tv \cdot Tu 
$$